# get data from last 7 days and get rows and data inserted count according to day

Tags: android, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Here's my sqlite table:

```
TimeStamp | Counter
--------- | --------
(in ms)     ...
```

And I want result something like this

```
| Day | Sum(Counter) |
----------------------
|Monday|10          |
|Tuesday| 20         |
```

Comment: What is the format of the time stamp values?

Comment: it's  in milliseconds

Comment: Days in which time zone? UTC or local?

Comment: Days are in local time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milliseconds is not one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), but it is possible to use Unix Time by multiplying/dividing by 1000 at the appropriate places.

In SQLite, a [date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with these modifiers returns the start of the current day in the local time zone:

```
datetime('now', 'localtime', 'start of day')
```

To convert this to milliseconds, use `strftime` instead:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE TimeStamp >= strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day', '-7 days') * 1000
...
```

To get the day of a timestamp, you have to use `strftime` again:

```
SELECT strftime('%w', TimeStamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS Day,
       sum(Counter)
FROM MyTable
WHERE TimeStamp >= strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day', '-7 days') * 1000
GROUP BY 1;
```

If you want to use day names instead of the day number, use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT CASE strftime('%w', TimeStamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
         WHEN '0' THEN 'Sunday'
         WHEN '1' THEN 'Monday'
         ...
       END AS Day,
       sum(Counter)
...
```